# My IRB is not producing the output,got blanked after clicking on the ENTER

Tags: ruby, irb

When I tried to do some operations on the line `m = %r(.)(.)(\d+)(\d)/.match("THX1138.")` (taken from the [doc](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/MatchData.html#method-i-5B-5D) ) nothing coming to the screen as below:

[image: screen]

`>` from the `IRB` went out and `\` came and the cursor is started to blink as above screenshot.

What wrong I did could you guide me?

Thanks

---

***As per @valodzka suggestion I tried the below and got back `>` return from the `/`. yippyy:)***

```
irb(main):006:0> m = %r(.)(.)(\d+)(\d)/.match("THX1138.")
irb(main):007:1/ /)
SyntaxError: (irb):6: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting $end
m = %r(.)(.)(\d+)(\d)/.match("THX1138.")
          ^
        from C:/Ruby193/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
irb(main):008:0>
```

Thank you very much ***@valodzka*** :)

Comment: But with my wrong syntax what causes `IRB` to show `"/"`  instead of  `>` ? Why the operator changed?

Comment: It shows / to tell you you have an unmatched / in your last line of code.

Comment: You are still in the middle of a regex.

Comment: @sawa this is situation I never came accross, thus asked here,why it happened? and what to do when happened without closing the `IRB` window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regexp syntax is wrong, should be:

```
m = /(.)(.)(\d+)(\d)/.match("THX1138.")
```

or

```
m = %r/(.)(.)(\d+)(\d)/.match("THX1138.")
```

Docs are definetly not correct. Ruby regexp syntax is `/regexp/` or `%r'open-symbol'regexp'close-symbol'`, for example `/test/` or `%r{test}` or `%r|test|`. Usually `//` used, but in some cases when regexp contains '/' symbol `%r` form can be usefull.

Comment: Okay! let me give it a try! I followed the doc as mentioned in the description.

Comment: You may have followed the doc, but you introduced a typo. The doc would not include the typo.

Comment: @valodzka perfect explanation - but how again to move to `>` from `/`?

Comment: @DoLoveSky you can enter `/)` (then you will get `SyntaxError` message) and then start again. Or simply close this window and open new.

Comment: `+1` for suggesting me a good trick! :)

Comment: just one information i need from you,if you have no problem- is how to clear the `IRB` screen if needed?

Comment: the only generic solution that will work always: close window and open it again. When using unix Ctlr+C might work, not sure about windows.